# How can I have links to anchors in menus?

Tags: 8, navigation

How can I add a menu link as /test#anchor and link to #anchor section on the test page?

I need to add a menu item that links to specific section on the target page. Drupal 7 had menu tokens to achieve it. How can I do this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add/edit a menu link
2. Enter  `/test#anchor` in the "Link" field
3. Save the link
4. You're done, make tea :)

Point being - fragments are accepted as part of the link in Drupal 8.

One exception seems to be the home page; it doesn't work with the `<front>` token, nor `/#anchor`. The fragment isn't rendered in either case.

Comment: Correct. I did the same but it's not working. There is a menu item in the footer that has anchored link menu item which does not seem to work as expected.

Comment: I just added a link `/node/1#test` and that worked fine. Maybe your theme is stripping it, try switching to a core theme temporarily to see

Comment: Right on the money. Theme was stripping it off. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the homepage enter:
`<front>#your-anchor` in the **link field**